# API Key content encryption

Tags: api, rest, encryption

I just started experimenting with RESTful APIs.

Generally, two kinds exist: open APIs and private APis for which you need API keys. What exactly are API keys used for? Can they ensure data encryption as well? I am confused because some API providers have 2 sets of keys, one public and another private perhaps pointing towards data and content security as well?

To sum up, if I query the database using a RESTful API and its key, the response that I receive from the database will be secure/encrypted or APIs keys are just used to authenticate source of request?

Comment: This question might be better suited for [security.se]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API keys are normally used for identification and authentication, not encryption. The client includes them in requests, so the server can figure out which client is making the request and be confident the call is really coming from that client.

(Sometimes API keys are used for identification, sometimes not. It's possible to make the API key like a password, so the client is also required to identify themselves with a username or client ID. But the trend is not to bother with this, and just issue sufficiently complex API keys that they will be unique across all users.)

In the simplest case, the server just looks up the API key and gets back a user ID. This normally happens at the beginning of the server's request-response cycle, and after that point, the client ID can be used for any further checks and logging, so the API key is no longer relevant.

In terms of data encryption, it's not clear why you want to do that on the server-side. It's common to encrypt passwords and indeed it's good practice to encrypt API keys too, but those are just the credentials. You wouldn't normally encrypt actual data on the server. It can be done in corner cases as a means of "host-proof hosting" where the client doesn't want to trust the server with their data, but that severely limits the server's functionality.

Comment: thanks a ton man..i am finally getting to wrap my head around APIs and their keys.. however..the thing that confused me was this -https://www.docebo.com/lms-docebo-api-third-party-integration/ any ideas on how they explained the use of two keys?? I initially thought that they were using this to encrypt data...

Comment: So, if i had to use their APIs(lets say the authenticate the user) then which of the two keys would identify/validate me to the server? Both? then how? and if only one..then what is the use of the other one? I am researching the APIs and their implementation for a project..so kindly excuse my noob questions.. ;-P

Comment: They are using a key to identify and a separate secret to authenticate, instead of just using a single (longer + guaranteed unique) API key to do both, similar to Twitter which uses this kind of scheme for every app a developer account has registered. Once the authentication happens, they will probably only care about the key (and it's associated client record).